# Problem involving trace and determinant of symmetric matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant, trace

I've stumbled upon this exercise on a linear algebra book that asks me to determine all the ordered pairs $(a,b)$ of real numbers to which there exists an unique symmetric matrix $A\in R^{2\times 2}$ so that $tr(A)=a$ and $Det(A)=b$.
I don't even know how to tackle this problem, I've tried using Laplace expansion, and other properties of the trace and determinants.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I'm not sure I got what you're asking for, could you be more clear?

Answer (score 4):

The characteristic polynomial of a $2 \times 2$ matrix can be written as: 
\begin{equation}
p(\lambda) = \lambda^2 - \textrm{tr}(A)\lambda + \textrm{det}(A)
\end{equation}
(Check [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Characteristic_polynomial)). If a matrix $A$ is symmetric then it is diagonalizable such that:
\begin{equation}
A = Q \Lambda Q^T \quad \textrm{ where } \quad \Lambda= \textrm{diag}(\lambda_1,\lambda_2)
\end{equation}
(*i.e.* $\Lambda$ is the matrix with eigenvalues in its diagonal). Therefore we can assume the characteristic polynomial can be solved for real roots: 
\begin{equation}
\lambda^2 - \underbrace{\textrm{tr}(A)}_{a}\lambda + \underbrace{\textrm{det}(A)}_{b} = 0
\end{equation}

The problem is therefore reduced to finding for which $(a,b)$ there is a solution to: 
\begin{equation}
\lambda^2 - a\lambda + b = 0
\end{equation}

The roots of the equation are given by the usual [formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation): 
\begin{equation}
\lambda = \frac{a \pm \sqrt{a^2 - 4b}}{2}
\end{equation}

Real-valued solutions are the ones where $a^2 \geq 4b$. This solves the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A=\pmatrix{x&z\\z&y}$. Then you have the equations $a = x+y$ and $b=xy-z^2$. It shouldn’t be too hard to solve these. You’ll have one free parameter when you’re done.